# How to put delay in multiple API request with delay in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am hitting an API request in JMeter by reading a CSV file, which has 130 records.I want to execute those 130 records within 5 minutes and then put a delay of 30 minutes then again execute those 130 records. What I have done up till now is:

- Created a thread group
- Created a loop controller with loop count 2 and
- Added the request with CSV under the loop controller
- Added a constant timer to the loop controller with a delay of 30 minutes.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following configuration:

1. Thread Group - set `Loop Count` to `2`.
2. Loop Controller - set `Loop Count` to `130`
3. Add `CSV Dataset Config` under `Loop Controller`
4. Add `If Controller` under `Loop Controller` to know the last loop. put the condition as `${__counter(,)}==130`
5. Add `Constant Timer` under `If Controller` and set the value to `30 minutes`
6. Add `Debug Sampler` under `If Controller` to make `Constant Timer` applicable. (without any sampler, timers won't apply)

Added the screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. But now the problem I am facing is that the delay of 30 minutes is not working. Is there any specific debug configuration?

Comment: please share your test plan screenshot. there is nothing to configure in Debug sampler. It just works.

Comment: please find the link at the starting of my question

Comment: remove `comma`. keep `1800000`